# htaccess redirect based on referrer URL string

Tags: htaccess, redirects, apache, referrer, regex

I have a 3rd party who `POST`'s to a specific page on my website.  They post a file and my site does some wizardry with the contents of that file.

The request URL would be for example `https://example.com/product-configrator`

Sometimes they use a string in their `REFERER` url like:

```
https://referrer.com/embed/section.htm?bikes=1
```

If the referrer passes traffic to me with the argument `bikes=1`  (contained within the `HTTP_REFERER` rather than the `QUERY_STRING`)  I'd like to serve up a different page.

Here's an example of an access.log entry where the 3rd party is posting to my site:

```
 90.xxx.xxx.xxx- - [21/Oct/2019:15:03:51 +0000] "POST /product-configurator HTTP/1.1" 200 23505 "https://referrer.com/embed/products.htm?bikes=1" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36"
```

So, they're `POST`ing to my `/product-configrator` page.  I want to redirect this to `/bikes-configrator` retaining the `POST` data (using a 307)

I've tested a redirect using some [htaccess syntax testing tools](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=6022f437-0e62-570a-a6ca-22ad2ca36be5) but can't get the correct syntax.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^(.*)\.referrer\.(.*)./*bikes* [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/bikes-configurator [R=307,L]
```

How can I do this? I know this question has been done to death but I can't see an example that matches my question.  I've also asked this question recently on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58465068/htaccess-redirect-based-on-referrer-url-string) but the responses I received didn't help me construct a valid entry in my .htaccess file.  Any help gratefully appreciated.

Comment: Any specific reason why you want to _externally_ "redirect" the request rather than _internally_ "rewrite" the request - as the destination appears to be on the same server? (Does the 3rd party follow redirects? Or is this simply a request via a browser?) Are you _only_ wanting to "redirect" POST requests? (Your example rule with also redirect GET.)

Comment: If there's a way rewrite internally then that's even better, but I need to retain the POST data (I thought a 307 redirect was the only way of doing this).  The 3rd party does nothing except POST to my site - they don't issue any GETS.  The rule would just need to work for any traffic coming from the referrer with that string `bikes=1` in the `HTTP_REFERER` string

Comment: How is `/bikes-configurator` then routed in your app? (This presumably does not map directly to a physical file?)

Comment: There's a PHP test - something like `if (isset($_POST["bike"])) { do stuff ...}`

Comment: So which PHP file is handling the request?

Comment: It's `/product-configurator`  (but the `if` exists on both `/product-configurator` and `/bikes-configurator`)

Comment: But that's not a PHP file. When you request `/product-configurator`, Apache needs to route the request to a physical script in order to handle the request. (eg. Many CMS's have a front-controller that sends all requests to `index.php`.)

Comment: "the if exists on both `/product-configurator` and `/bikes-configurator`" - so why do you need to redirect/rewrite the request? Shouldn't the `Referer` just be checked in PHP and act accordingly?

Comment: In that case, it would be `/product-configurator.php`.  If this can be handled in PHP, how would I redirect/rewrite the referrer by testing the `HTTP-REFERER` url?

Comment: So, your URLs are just extensionless? `/foo` maps to `/foo.php`? Presumably you have other directives in your `.htaccess` file that handle this? (Or are you using MultiViews?)

Answer (score 1):

To *externally* redirect the request from `/product-configurator` (I assume the missing `u` was a typo?) to `/bikes-configurator` when the HTTP `Referer` contains `bikes=1` in the query string part of the URL then you could do something like the following using mod_rewrite near the top of your `.htaccess` in the document root:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} \?.*\bbikes=1\b [NC]
RewriteRule ^product-configurator$ /bikes-configurator [R=307,L]
```

The `RewriteCond` directive checks for the URL parameter `bikes=1` *anywhere* in the query string of the `Referer` HTTP request header.

If this is intended to work for "any traffic" (as suggested in a comment), not just requests for `/product-configurator` then change the `RewriteRule` *pattern* to something like `^` instead.

The 307 status is required for the user-agent to preserve the HTTP method in the redirected request.

Note that this redirects *all* requests, POST and GET. You could specifically redirect only POST requests if you wish by checking against the `REQUEST_METHOD` server variable.

> The 3rd party does nothing except POST to my site

The "3rd party" needs to be able to follow redirect responses (and submit the 2nd request). An ordinary HTML form submission in a browser will naturally follow the redirect. However, a scripted CURL (for example) may not.

---

However, it's not clear why you would need to "redirect" the request since this is all happening on the same server. You could potentially *internally rewrite* the request instead (no external redirect, no second request, quicker and more efficient all round). However, `/product-configurator` and `/bikes-configurator` require further routing to get to your PHP script - so "rewriting" to `/bikes-configurator` is not correct.

> **UPDATE:** In that case, it would be `/product-configurator.php`

Assuming you are just using extensionless URLs and the underlying file that handles the request is simply `/bikes-configurator.php` then you can perhaps implement an *internal rewrite* instead.

For example, instead of the above, this would be written as:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} \?.*\bbikes=1\b [NC]
RewriteRule ^product-configurator$ /bikes-configurator.php [L]
```

The URL in the address bar stays as `/product-configurator`, but the request is internally rewritten (note the absence of the `R` flag) to `/bikes-configurator.php` when `bikes=1` is included in the query string of the HTTP `Referer`. There is no external redirect.

This may also be solvable directly in your PHP script - no additional redirect/rewrite in `.htaccess` required. (Although from your recent comments, it looks like the request `/bike-configurator` is simply extensionless and the request maps to the PHP file `/bike-configurator.php`? The logic that tests the HTTP_REFERER would need to be in `/product-configurator.php` - you then make the necessary PHP calls to pass control to `/bike-configurator.php` if the condition is met - but exactly how you do this depends on the structure of your app.)

Comment: How did you get on with this?